Does any connected graph have a vertex which is closest to most vertices?
Let $G$ be a connected graph. Does there always exist a vertex $u$ such that for any vertex $v$ the following holds: the number of vertices $a$ with $d(a,u) < d(a,v)$ is greater than or equal to the number of vertices $a$ with $d(a,u) > d(a,v)$? (Here $d(a,b)$ denotes the length of a shortest path between $a$ and $b$.)
If $G$ is a tree on $n$ vertices, then a working vertex is such that when removing it, all resulting connected components have at most $\frac{n}{2}$ vertices. But everything becomes more complicated when cycles are present.
Any help appreciated!

I think this might be true for all connected graphs (at least I didn't manage to find a counterexample). I tried proving it by picking $u$ to be a vertex which minimizes $\sum_{a \neq u}d(u,a)$. Then for any $v\in N(u)$ your condition should be satisfied using the triangle inequality. I then tried to prove it for vertices $v$ such that $d(u,v) >1$, via induction over $d(u,v)$. I didn't manage to do the induction step unfortunately. Hope it helps in any way.

Any set of nonnegative integers has a minimum.  Why is this not enough?

@GEdgar how do you prove that if $u$ is as defined by Immi then it satisfies the problem conditions?

@DesmondMiles Just a remark: by the minimax theorem, there is a distribution over $u$'s that works.

There is the following counterexample.
Let $H$ be any graph and $h$ be any vertex of $H$.
Let $G$ be the graph from the picture , where the grey regions represent copies of $H$ attached to the vertices of the triangle by an edge from the copy of $h$.

It is easy to see that for any vertex $u$ of $G$ there is a vertex $v$ of the triangle such that there are two vertices of the triangle which are closer to $v$ than to $u$ and all vertices from the copies
of $H$ attached to these two vertices of the triangle are closer to $v$ than to $u$.

I think this is correct, but could use elaboration. Let $u$ be a vertex of $G$. One of the black vertices $b$ is uniquely closest to $u$; then take $v$ to be a white vertex on the side of the triangle opposite $b$ (take the one nearest to $u$ if the two are not equidistant from $u$). Among those vertices of $G$ not on the triangle, exactly twice as many are closer to $v$ than to $u$. Among those vertices of $G$ on the triangle, at least four are closer to $u$ than to $v$ and at most four are closer to $v$ than to $u$. Therefore $u$ does not meet the requirement so long as $H$ is not empty.
